# What is Oncogene, and how do you get it?

Tags: pathology

I was looking at my family tree and it said that one of my family members died by Oncogene. What is it and how do you get it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An oncogene is a gene that has the potential to cause cancer. If an oncogene is activated, it will contribute towards cancer, though there are typically many other factors necessary before cancer becomes noticeable and potentially lethal.

In short, your family member presumably died of cancer, though writing the cause of death as "oncogene" is highly abnormal.

Many normal and healthy genes can cause cancer when they are overly active. For example, [PDGF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platelet-derived_growth_factor) produces a growth factor required for normal health, but if too much growth factor is produced it can cancer like breast cancer.

Comment: Oh. Thank you. Well now I know why she died. Have a good life, live it to the fullest (but not by smoking or drugs) and have fun. I hope I get to talk to you again.